# How to pass Python-objects into argparse to execute a script?

Tags: python, shell, automation, console, arguments

I have a script that I want to be able to execute in my console with arguments, so I restructured everything to work with argsparse. Regular types work easily, but I have a problem with a more complex object. It requires passing some callable objects to it to work. How would I be able to pass callable objects in the console (with argsparse)?

Is there any good way to tackle this situation? How does one deal with Python objects that can be passed as arguments?

Any help is highly appreciated!

**Edit:**

Here is an example of what I would (currently) need to call:

```
python my_script.py --text_callable TextCallable("some_file.txt")
```

I don't know how I would do that currently. I can't instantiate a Python object in the console. Or would I be able to pass a config file and load stuff from there? I am a complete novice.

Comment: Please provide an example, in code, of what you are trying to do. The only thing you can pass from the console are *strings*, and it's not entirely clear what you want to do with them in `argparse`.

Comment: @chepner I added further information to my question.

Comment: You can't (or rather, shouldn't) do that; passing arbitrary Python code to execute could be a security risk. Pass the name of the file, and your *script* should pass the file name to `TextCallable`.

Comment: @chepner That's one way, but my problem is that I have around 20 callables that could be passed and each can be created with up to 4-5 arguments each. The TextCallable was just an example. Any idea on how to deal with that? Or just write all in a script and run it without arguments?

Comment: You should probably write one script.